# Nuevo repositorio Git a partir de otro

Tags: git, git-commit

Tengo un repositorio Git 'git1' que tiene cerca de 35.000 commits. Necesito crear un nuevo repositorio 'git2' que contenga los últimos 1.000 commits de git1, existe alguna forma de hacer esto??

Comment: Debes revisar [ask] ya que . si la respuesta te "ayuda" pero no resuelve el problema porque marcar como solución?, debes ser más especifico en lo que deseas al preguntar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo lo he hecho un par de veces siguiendo lo que dice [este artículo](https://passingcuriosity.com/2017/truncating-git-history/).

Primero clonas el repo `git1`. Luego cambias el remoto para apuntar a `git2`.

Identificas el `sha` del commit que será tu nuevo commit original. En tu caso el que está 1000 commits detrás de `HEAD`

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD~1000
e41d7f633c45c46bd42e97cecf93204191d9e4c9
```

Te dice que el `sha` de tu nuevo root será `e41d7f633c45c46bd42e97cecf93204191d9e4c9` pero por cariño vamos a decirle `e41d7f633`.

```
git checkout --orphan temp e41d7f633
git commit -m "Nuevo primer commit"
git rebase --onto temp e41d7f633 master
```

Y luego pusheas a `git2`.

Nótese que los `sha` desde tu primer commit hasta el presente habrán cambiado producto del rebase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero en tu ejemplo borraría todos los commits y el proyecto iniciaría nuevamente, hay alguna manera en que pueda conservar estos últimos 1000 commits??

Comment: No borrarías los commits. Reescribirías su `sha`. Eso es inevitable.

Comment: @WalterFabianRodriguezSalaza, si te ha servido la respuesta te sugiero que la des por aceptada o al menos +1,  saludos